# glossaries: fail to expand in tabularx

Tags: glossaries, tabularx

When I use an acronym (glossaries or acronym package) for the first time in tabularx, then it fails to expand, and even breaks down the table structure. The problem is already mentioned [here](http://comp.text.tex.narkive.com/OVYHzaRs/glossaries-fail-to-expand-in-tabularx), but there is no straightforward solution provided.

The problem does not appear with `\acf`, `\acs` or other commands that do not check for the first time usage of the entry. However, it is not a solution, as the whole idea of this package is automatic checking. I am looking for a simple solution with not too much processing overhead, as I have thousands of `\ac` commands in my text.

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newacronym{BI}{BI}{Beacon Interval}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Parameter & Value \\ \hline
\ac{BI}  & Typical: 0.1 seconds. I heard somebody say, that the sentence ended here, But everyone knows it's goin' still. \\
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Parameter & Value \\ \hline
\ac{BI}  & Typical: 0.1 seconds. I heard somebody say, that the sentence ended here, But everyone knows it's goin' still. \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you make your snippet of code into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I just tried it using the `acronym` package. Works fine with `tabular`. Sadly, this does not work correctly with `tabularx`, too.

Comment: I changed it to a complete MWE.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea that an acronym appears for the first time in the tabular. The obvious problem is that `tabularx` makes two passes over the material, so on the first pass it expands the "new" acronym, but on the second pass the acronym has been marked as "already seen" and so not expanded any more.

Comment: @egreg, I agree, and try to avoid such an occasion. However, the procedure is somewhat automatic. I have a long text full of acronyms. If I remove a paragraph (that has an acronym) from an early chapter, then the acronym may appear somewhere else for its first time. I don't want to end up with unpredictable layout issues when there is no time to review the whole document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newacronym{BI}{BI}{Beacon Interval}
\makeatletter


\def\foo#1\hbox#2#3!!{%
\def\TX@trial##1{#1\hbox{\let\glsunset\@gobble#2}#3}%
}
\expandafter\foo\TX@trial{#1}!!
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\noindent X \dotfill X

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Parameter & Value \\ \hline
\ac{BI}  & Typical: 0.1 seconds. I heard somebody say, that the sentence ended here, But everyone knows it's goin' still. \\
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Parameter & Value \\ \hline
\ac{BI}  & Typical: 0.1 seconds. I heard somebody say, that the sentence ended here, But everyone knows it's goin' still. \\
\end{tabularx}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added a working example to the question. Your code does not solve the problem completely, but spreads the table into page margin.

Comment: Code updated to work with supplied example

Answer (score 5):

Following on from David's answer, version 4.28 (2017-01-07) of `glossaries` now has a command `\glspatchtabularx` that does David's patch without the need for `\makeatletter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newacronym{BI}{BI}{Beacon Interval}

\glspatchtabularx

\begin{document}


\noindent X \dotfill X

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Parameter & Value \\ \hline
\ac{BI}  & Typical: 0.1 seconds. I heard somebody say, that the
sentence ended here, But everyone knows it's goin' still. \
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Parameter & Value \\ \hline
\ac{BI}  & Typical: 0.1 seconds. I heard somebody say, that the
sentence ended here, But everyone knows it's goin' still. \
\end{tabularx}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\end{document}
```

It will do nothing if `tabularx` hasn't been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, and already made upstream, but I think I have an alternative solution which might not need to patch `tabularx`. The idea is that `tabularx` performs a number of trials before typesetting the table, but when they are over, before the final step, `\@footnotetext` is let to `\TX@ftntext`, and this assignment could be used to identify the trials are over:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newacronym{BI}{BI}{Beacon Interval}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glsunset}[1]{%
  \ifx\@footnotetext\TX@ftntext
    \gls@ifnotmeasuring
    {%
      \glsdoifexists{#1}%
      {%
        \@glsunset{#1}%
      }%
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Parameter & Value \\ \hline
\ac{BI}  & Typical: 0.1 seconds. I heard somebody say, that the sentence ended here, But everyone knows it's goin' still. \\
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Parameter & Value \\ \hline
\ac{BI}  & Typical: 0.1 seconds. I heard somebody say, that the sentence ended here, But everyone knows it's goin' still. \\
\end{tabularx}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Of course, this is just "proof of concept", but if this check is indeed solid for the situation, it would not be difficult to provide something similar to `\gls@ifnotmeasuring` based on it.

Comment: yes I think I have a comment in an issue somewhere that I should have provided an \ifTX@... test for that, see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352134/) or more generally [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227155/1090) I think I patched TX in my original answer just so I only needed to touch my code rather than patch glossaries in code I didn't know to add a test. I didn't know that glossaries now does that patch...

Comment: Oh! There are other similar assignments then that could be used. Well, a formal test like the `amsmath`'s `\ifmeasuring@` would be nice, of course. And `glossaries` does not patch by default, but users can enable the patch. Problem there is if more people (packages, that is) need it. As things currently stand, is there any reason to prefer one or other or these assignments to identify the final pass?

Comment: Not really, as you see in the code I made (a long long time ago) some random set of functions safe (or quiet) while doing the tests. Just pick one, I should add a newif token there I think (perhaps I should not have an `@` so you can use it in documents `\ifTXfinal \typeout{helllo}\fi`  ?? One issue I never had a good answer to is what the calling package (or document) should do in the trial case. It is easy to avoid errors by doing "nothing" but if that changes the effective width of the column it means the trials are broken and won't necessarily end up with widths that work on the final pass

Comment: Ok, thanks! I guess I'll use the `\savedwrite`/`\write` one for being a little more semantic. Regarding what to do in the trial passes, it is difficult, and I guess depends on the case. In my case at the moment, I'm working with end notes, so what I do is add a "dumb" mark to take the space of what will be typeset in the final pass, so that the measurement is not tripped, but refrain from doing other operations, like adding the note to the "queue" sequence, not to get duplicated notes later on.