# epstopdf does not find figure within tabularx environment

Tags: beamer, tabularx, epstopdf

I am using MiKTeX and running into a very strange issue when using EPS figures within a `tabularx` environment. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\graphicspath{{../Icons_Cisco/}}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./} %Required since more recent MiKTeX versions - the converted figure is not found otherwise
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}

  \begin{figure}
    %\includegraphics{cloud}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{0.4\textwidth}m{0.4\textwidth}}
      \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{cloud}
      \end{figure} & Picture of a cloud\\
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This should produce a beamer slide with a cloud icon (when using the icons from http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/about/ac50/ac47/3015_eps.zip) and the text "Picture of a cloud". However, it fails to generate an output file with the following error message:

> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./cloud-eps-converted-to.pdf' not
>   found.

The weird thing is, though, when uncommenting the commented line which includes the cloud icon outside the `tabularx` environment, I get a slide with two cloud icons. I presume that the EPS to PDF conversion is run only once per file, but I cannot find an explanation why it does not work inside the `tabularx` environment.

Is this a known issue or am I missing something obvious? Adding extra figures to my presentations is not really an option.

Comment: Why not converting the files before compilation?

Comment: There are a lot of files and it is more convenient to have them converted on the fly. Besides, I am curious why the `tabularx` environment makes the conversion fail.

Comment: FWIW, I can replicate the issue you're reporting when compiling your code with pdfLaTeX, but not with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger: Does it work with a non-`beamer` class?

Comment: Incidentally, you're abusing the `tabularx` environment: At least one of the columns should be of type `X` (or based on the `X` column type).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: When I use the `article` class, I get `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` Removing the figure environment inside `tabularx` fails again at the conversion as describe above.

Comment: I removed the incorrect figure environment in my answer (it doesn't give an error in beamer but it's wrong anyway)

Comment: @Mico yes that's because newer luatex don't use `\write` to implement shell-escape.

Comment: You should *never* have a `figure` environment inside a `table` environment; that's why you're getting the "not in outer par mode" error message when using the `article` class. The `beamer` class disables much of the code of the `figure` and `table` environments, since it makes little (actually, no!) sense to use floats in a `beamer` document. Nevertheless, don't use a `figure` environment here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks, I didn't know about this difference in the use of `\write`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tabularx disables `\writes` during trials so you can do

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\graphicspath{{../Icons_Cisco/}}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./} %Required since more recent MiKTeX versions - the converted figure is not found otherwise
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}

  \begin{figure}
    %\includegraphics{cloud}
  \end{figure}

\let\savedwrite\write
  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{0.4\textwidth}m{0.4\textwidth}}
       \ifx\savedwrite\write\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cloud}\fi
       & Picture of a cloud\\
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So that it only does the image on the last run, but really doing the conversion on the fly is an unnecessary complication, I'd just convert the EPS file to PDF once on the commandline before running pdftex, then `\includegraphics{cloud}` would use the PDF not the EPS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explains the behavior and offers a practical solution.