# How to identify a trial pass in tabularray?

Tags: tabularray

`tabularray`, just like `tabularx`, performs "trial" passes with its tables to calculate the size of things before a final pass where the table is actually typeset. This means that the contents of the table get to be processed multiple times, with some known implications.  For example, `tabularray` offers the `counter` library to restore the value of counters set inside a `tabularray` tables.

Here on the site, there are a number of techniques for identifying trial passes for `tabularx`, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227155/105447, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352134/105447, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640035/105447.

So, the question is, is there an "official" method of distinguishing a trial from a final pass in `tabularray`? Failing that, are there any known reliable techniques, similar or equivalent to the ones existing for `tabularx`?

A MWE for the problem:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewDocumentCommand{\onlyfinal}{}{%
  % if trial
  %   do nothing
  % else (if final)
  %   do something, for example:
  \typeout{Dinner.}
  \typeout{Oh no!}
  % And, of course, no one wants dinner four times in a row.
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {@{}X[c]X[l]X[c]X[r]X[c]@{}},
  hlines, vlines,
}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4\onlyfinal & 5 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: there seem to be since last month \lTblrMeasuringBool, see https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/179 (i don't know if it is already on ctan).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's good news, and exactly what I need. Thank you. It seems not to be released yet, but will eventually arrive. Would you like to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered by @UlrikeFischer in the comments).

Since last month, `tabularray` has `\lTblrMeasuringBool` for precisely this purpose (see https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/179). It is not yet released, but should eventually hit CTAN.